# Difference between casper.then() and this.then()

Tags: javascript, casperjs

How is the `then()` function executed? Is it different if I call it with referring to `this` object?

I mean:

```
casper.then(function() {
        casper.then(function(){
            // stuff
            this.then(function() {
                // stuff2
            });
            casper.then();
        });
});

casper.then(function() {
        this.then(function(){
            casper.then();
            this.then();
            // stuff
        });
});
```

Is it the same (execution order?)? It should be, isn't it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no real difference. Most of the time it is just a shortcut (2 characters).

Every callback is bound to the calling `casper` object. `this` is essentially local scope, so the execution environment doesn't need to search for it in other higher scopes. Whereas the `casper` reference is defined in the global scope and requires a search which takes a little time. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/500459/1816580) is a good write-up of scopes.

There are rare occasions that you need to use the global `casper` variable instead of `this`. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24883847/1816580) is an example for that.

Beware: If you are in the test environment `this` in the `casper.test.begin` callback will reference `casper.test`.