# Difference between scraping and testing mode in CasperJS

Tags: casperjs

I'm absolutely new to CasperJS and I'm wondering what's the difference between those 'two modes'.

Both access the DOM, it seems that test mode has a limited access and functionality.

I looked for this question around and didn't find the answer.

Answer (score 1):

In test mode you have access to the [tester module](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/tester.html) and with it access to asserts, test suites and (xml) reports. This is not accessible in plain mode anymore (earlier versions than 1.1-beta4 had access to some of the test mode stuff in plain mode).

The only drawback to test mode is that you can only have one casper instance which is injected. This leads to:

- When you try to create it, you will get an error.
- (Nearly) *all* options have to be assigned directly and cannot be passed to `create` as an object.
- Some things cannot be done like this one: [A: How to open a new tab in CasperJS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24883847/1816580)

Comment: Very well, thanks, i'll look fo more testing examples and assert.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're after. Here are some examples, how people use the test environment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bcasperjs%5D+%22casper+test%22

Comment: Well, i'm creating some kind of monitoring service (kebanna, elasticSearch...). I just need some inside in wich is the best aprroach. You have been most helpfull.