# CasperJS WaitFor not waiting for the condition to finish

Tags: javascript, testing, asynchronous, casperjs

I'm relatively new to casperJS.I have script where i want to perform operation in page B(i.e Verify the confirmation mail for user),then proceed with execution in page A.code snippet is as follows

```
casper.waitFor(function(){
   return this.run(function(){
     return verifyEmail(user_details['email']);
  });
},function then(){
   this.wait(60000, function() {
   this.reload(function(){
     this.echo("Refresh");
     this.capture('after-reload-a.png');
    });
  });   
});
```

and the function verifyEmail is defined as follows:

```
function verifyEmail(email){
    return casper.open('someURL').then(function(response){
        //extract URL from response
                    this.echo("URL"+url);
        casper.start().thenOpen(url, function() {
            this.waitForText('someText',function(){
                this.capture("final.jpg");
            });
        });
        return url;
    });
};
```

During the execution,Casper never executes the function verifyEmail(URL is never printed) and proceeds with then() function.What am i missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `start` and `run` functions only once per `casper` instance in your script. Since CasperJS' execution is asynchronous, you can't return something. You have to wait for it.

You can use a second `casper` instance to set a global variable and use a `waitFor` in the previous instance to wait for it to change as seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24883847/1816580).

Depending on how you extract the URL from the response, it might be easier to use [`__utils__.sendAJAX(someURL)`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/clientutils.html#sendajax) in the page context (through `casper.evaluate`). Note that this shouldn't be done in a `casper.waitFor`, because it has a default synchronous mode where wait is not necessary. Besides the first function callback of `waitFor` is called very often to check if a value changed, so it shouldn't be used that way.

The third possibility is to simply navigate using only one instance. It seems that you reload the original page after you parsed the other page. Why don't you normally visit `'someURL'` with `thenOpen`, do your parsing and then open the original URL with `thenOpen` without any waiting? You can even [get the current URL](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#getcurrenturl) and save it a (semi-)global variable to make sure you come back to the correct page.

Comment: How this can be achieved using casperJS test instance?is it possible to  spawn two instance?

Comment: It isn't possible. However, maybe you can completely forget about a second instance or ajax. It seems that you reload the original page. Why don't you normally visit `'someURL'` with `thenOpen`, do your parsing and then open the original URL with `thenOpen` without any waiting? You can even get the current URL to make sure you come back to the correct page.