# how to load another page in casperjs?

Tags: javascript, casperjs

I am  testing website and then I come across a link I want to open and continue testing the second web page

```
 casper.start('http://Firstsite.com', function() {
 //blablah my codeing 


    casper.start('http://Secondesite.com', function() { 
   //blablah my codeing for ('http://Secondesite.com', )
    });


 });
```

Comment: Hi, i think that's already answerd in this [Post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24880671/how-to-open-a-new-tab-in-casperjs) . Anyways, why you don't save the current url, then do your stuff and go back to the saved url?

Comment: @dasmelch Thanks , I saw all post before posting the question but I am looking for a simple solution.see the answer below.

Answer (score 1):

I found a very simple solution at Casperjs documentation page http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#

```
 casper.start('http://Firstsite.com', function() {
 //blablah my codeing 


  casper.thenOpen('http://Secondesite.com', function() { 
     //blablah my codeing for ('http://Secondesite.com', )
  });


});
```